# Grub doesn't recognize Win10 after first installing Win10 and then LinuxMint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, grub

So I was trying to set up a dual boot Win10/LinuxMint on my HP Pavilion by doing the following:

- Installing Win7 fresh from an HP Recovery Partition.
- Upgrading it to Win10.
- Installing LinuxMint from a live Version

I have the following partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` - Win10 System Partition 209MB
- `/dev/sda2` - Primary Win Install 401GB
- `/dev/sda3` - Recovery Partition Win7 15GB
- `/dev/sda4` - Extended Partition (Linux?) 85GB
- `/dev/sda5` - Swap Partition 8.8GB
- `/dev/sda6` - Linux Mint Install 76GB

Now in the Grub bootloader, it doesn't recognize Win10 itself, instead it recognizes the partitions sda1, sda2 and sda3 as 'Windows Recovery Manager'. It boots the HP Recovery Partition option on sda3 correctly, whereas the boot options on sda1 and sda2 go to some Windows 10 recovery diagnostics, which doesn't help at all.

How can I update Grub to recognize Windows 10, especially without losing the HP Recovery Partition on sda3?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Extended partitions (/dev/sda4) are an artifact of the MBR partitioning scheme.  It's a "hidden" partition that contains sda5 and sda6.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two ways :

```
1. Install os-prober package
2. Reconfigure grub after that using e.g. grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Check if it works, and if not, try installing and running boot-repair.